# Passing a string to macro assembler MASM

Tags: assembly, macros, x86, masm, irvine32

Ok so I have got this working to a degree but when I try to pass the variable name to the macro it says this:

error A2071: initializer magnitude too large for specified size

I don't see what I am doing wrong here. I am following the examples I have on how to pass parameters but that is what it gives me. So here is what I have so far.

```
TITLE MASM TestTExt                     (TestTExt.asm)

   ; Description:
   ;  
   ; Revision date:

   INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

   ;macro stuff

    mWriteString MACRO text
   LOCAL string
   .data
   string db text
   .code
    push edx
    mov  edx,OFFSET string
    call WriteString
    pop edx

    ENDM

    .data
    myStr db "Test1",0

    .code
   main PROC
   call Clrscr  
  mWriteString myStr
  call Crlf

  exit
   main ENDP

END main
```

Now this does not work, but if is put in a string like this "Some Thing" when I call the macro in the .code section, the macro works and go on its merry way. Why is that? Am I not passing the right string or did I not terminate the string right in my `.data` section?
The example I am using is like this

```
 .data
  myString   db   "abcefg",0
  .code
  mWriteString  myString
```

Comment: I haven't worked in MASM in a loooong time, but what happens if you do  just mWriteString "abcdefg", 0?

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem is that the line:

```
string db text
```

Is trying to store the offset of the `text` parameter into a byte.

It's been quite a while since I worked with assembly language macros, but I'm pretty sure you don't need that `.data` directive in the macro. The following should work just fine:

```
mWriteString MACRO text
push edx
mov  edx,OFFSET text
call WriteString
pop edx

ENDM
```

Answer (score 1):

Adam,

The errors, as I see it, is ...

in the macro ... 'string db text' must be zero terminated ... add ',0' at the end

in macro call ...

1) the '.data  myStr db "Test1",0' entry is not required ...

2) call your macro thus 'mWriteString "Any Text"' and it will setup the '.data' for you.

What this macro does is it enables you to directly write quoted strings. You can save it in a macro library and re-use it.

I know this is an old post, but hope it helps you ... or anyone else.

Regards,
Sam K